# Varnish 4, slow initial server response time

Tags: performance, http, response, varnish

I use

Apache > Wordpress > Woocommerce & Varnish

It works absolutely great when the initial connection has made, with HTTP Keep Alive and cached pages it works like a charm. But the initial HTTP request has a delay up to several seconds (also when the page is cached).

/etc/sysconfig/varnish

---

```
# Maximum number of threads (for ulimit -u)
NPROCS="unlimited"
RELOAD_VCL=1
VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret

# The minimum number of worker threads to start
VARNISH_MIN_THREADS=200

# The Maximum number of worker threads to start
VARNISH_MAX_THREADS=2000

# Idle timeout for worker threads
VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT=120

VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE=/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin
VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE=10G
VARNISH_STORAGE="file,${VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE},${VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE}"

# Default TTL used when the backend does not specify one
VARNISH_TTL=120

# DAEMON_OPTS is used by the init script.  If you add or remove options,    make
# sure you update this section, too.
DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \
         -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \
         -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \
         -t ${VARNISH_TTL} \
         -p thread_pool_min=${VARNISH_MIN_THREADS} \
         -p thread_pool_max=${VARNISH_MAX_THREADS} \
         -p thread_pool_timeout=${VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT} \
         -u varnish -g varnish \
         -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \
         -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"
```

And the /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.connect_timeout = 600s;
.first_byte_timeout = 600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
.max_connections = 800;
}

# Only allow purging from specific IPs
acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "127.0.0.1";
}

# This function is used when a request is send by a HTTP client (Browser)
sub vcl_recv {
    # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

    # Remove has_js and CloudFlare/Google Analytics __* cookies.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
    # Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
    set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

    # Allow purging from ACL
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
            # If not allowed then a error 405 is returned
            if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                    return(synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
            }
            # If allowed, do a cache_lookup -> vlc_hit() or vlc_miss()
            return (purge);
    }

    # Post requests will not be cached
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.method == "POST") {
            return (pass);
    }

    # --- WordPress specific configuration

    # Did not cache the admin and login pages
    if (req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)" || req.url ~ "preview=true") {
    return (pass);
    }

    # Remove the "has_js" cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp test cookie

    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "woocommerce_recently_viewed=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__atuv.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^ *$") {
                unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Cache the following files extensions
    if (req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g|swf|ico)") {
            unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Normalize Accept-Encoding header and compression
    # https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/vary.html
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
            # Do no compress compressed files...
            if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
                            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
            } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
                    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
            } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
                    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
            } else {
                    unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
            }
    }

    # Check the cookies for wordpress-specific items
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_") {
            return (pass);
    }
    if (!req.http.cookie) {
            unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # --- End of WordPress specific configuration

    # Did not cache HTTP authentication and HTTP Cookie
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
            # Not cacheable by default
            return (pass);
    }

    # Cache all others requests
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
        return (pipe);
}

sub vcl_pass {
    return (fetch);
}
# The data on which the hashing will take place
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
    hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
    hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # If the client supports compression, keep that in a different cache
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
            hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
    }

    return (lookup);
}

# This function is used when a request is sent by our backend (Nginx server)
sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Remove some headers we never want to see
    unset beresp.http.Server;
    unset beresp.http.X-Powered-By;

    # For static content strip all backend cookies
    if (bereq.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e?)g)|swf|ico") {
            unset beresp.http.cookie;
    }
    # Don't store backend
    if (bereq.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)" || bereq.url ~ "preview=true") {
            set beresp.uncacheable = true;
            set beresp.ttl = 30s;
            return (deliver);
    }

    # Only allow cookies to be set if we're in admin area
           if (!(bereq.url ~ "(wp-login|wp-admin|preview=true)")) {
            unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

    # don't cache response to posted requests or those with basic auth
    if ( bereq.method == "POST" || bereq.http.Authorization ) {
            set beresp.uncacheable = true;
            set beresp.ttl = 120s;
            return (deliver);
    }

    # don't cache search results
    if ( bereq.url ~ "\?s=" ){
            set beresp.uncacheable = true;
            set beresp.ttl = 120s;
            return (deliver);
    }

    # only cache status ok
    if ( beresp.status != 200 ) {
            set beresp.uncacheable = true;
            set beresp.ttl = 120s;
            return (deliver);
    }

    # A TTL of 2h
    set beresp.ttl = 2h;
    # Define the default grace period to serve cached content
    set beresp.grace = 30s;

    return (deliver);
}

# The routine when we deliver the HTTP request to the user
# Last chance to modify headers that are sent to the client
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "cached";
    } else {
            set resp.http.x-Cache = "uncached";
    }

    # Remove some headers: PHP version
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;

    # Remove some headers: Apache version & OS
    unset resp.http.Server;

    # Remove some heanders: Varnish
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_init {
    return (ok);
}

sub vcl_fini {
    return (ok);
}
```

It looks like the new request starts with a backend lookup in stead of presenting the cache? Any suggestions are highly appriciated.

Comment: You might get a better response over at https://serverfault.com/